# file size too big for nginx, 413 error

Tags: nginx

I am running a rails app on nginx and sending an image to my rails api via my ios app.

The IOS app keeps receiving this response from nginx:

```
 { status code: 413, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 207;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Sun, 17 Jul 2016 23:16:07 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)";
}
```

So I did `sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and added a large client_max_body_size.

Now my nginx.conf reads:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {


        #fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

        client_max_body_size 1000000M;
...
```

I ran `sudo service nginx reload` and got `[ OK ]`

But, my ios still gets the same response.

If I use a tiny image the IOS app gets a `200` response.

**Question**

Why does nginx give the 413 error when the `client_max_body_size` is so big?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to put

```
client_max_body_size 1000M;
```

In the server {} block where the sites nginx config is stored. Usually /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite

As mentioned, set the max size to whatever you need it to be.

Comment: Doing that expose you to hard DoS attack by overloading your server with 999999MB (1TB) files. You should define a reasonable limit on what you accept.